# RTK-georeferenced textured mesh with Meshroom (Drone imagery)

Tags: texture-mapping, photogrammetry, structure-from-motion, meshroom, real-time-kinematic

I'm quiet new to Meshroom and photogrammetry topics.
I want to compute a georeferenced textured mesh of a survey site with Meshroom. I have some sample drone images with RTK files (rinex.obs and timestamp.mrk) [withoud GCPs] to create a suitable workflow pipeline. So far I found no way to include the RTK-data in the pipeline. Are the rtk-corrected geotags already saved in the jpg or how do I get the thing running? When I let it compute withoud specifying the rtk-data the model turns out well. The problem is how to get it georeferenced? When I convert the obj-file into a las-file with CloudCompare and load it into QGIS no CRS is shown. Is there any tweak I oversaw?

Working on Desktop PC with the recent Meshroom release.

Appreciate some help! Thanks!

I saw a option with the SfMTransform-Node but putting in the RTK-data by markers seems not the be the soluton. Didn't found a option to import the RTK-files only by manually setting the markers.